# Problem with incomplete input when using Attoparsec

Tags: haskell, attoparsec

I am converting some functioning Haskell code that uses Parsec to instead use Attoparsec in the hope of getting better performance.  I have made the changes and everything compiles but my parser does not work correctly.

I am parsing a file that consists of various record types, one per line.  Each of my individual functions for parsing a record or comment works correctly but when I try to write a function to compile a sequence of records the parser always returns a partial result because it is expecting more input.

These are the two main variations that I've tried.  Both have the same problem.

```
items :: Parser [Item]
items = sepBy (comment <|> recordType1 <|> recordType2) endOfLine
```

For this second one I changed the record/comment parsers to consume the end-of-line characters.

```
items :: Parser [Item]
items = manyTill (comment <|> recordType1 <|> recordType2) endOfInput
```

Is there anything wrong with my approach? Is there some other way to achieve what I am attempting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run into this problem before and my understanding is that it's caused by the way that `<|>` works in the definition of `sepBy`:

```
sepBy1 :: Alternative f => f a -> f s -> f [a]
sepBy1 p s = scan
    where scan = liftA2 (:) p ((s *> scan) <|> pure [])
```

This will only move to `pure []` once `(s *> scan)` has failed, which won't happen just because you're at the end of the input.

My solution has been just to call `feed` with an `empty` ByteString on the `Result` returned by `parse`. This might be kind of a hack, but it also seems to be how [`attoparsec-iteratee`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec-iteratee/0.1.1/doc/html/src/Data-Attoparsec-Iteratee.html#parserToIteratee) deals with the issue:

```
f k (EOF Nothing)  = finalChunk $ feed (k S.empty) S.empty
```

As far as I can tell this is the only reason that `attoparsec-iteratee` works here and plain old `parse` doesn't.

Answer (score 6):

If you write an attoparsec parser that consumes as much input as possible before failing, you must tell the partial result continuation when you've reached the end of your input.

Comment: So `feed` is actually the correct way to deal with this situation? It might be a good idea to make this a little clearer in the documentation—I know it confused me when I first came across it.

Answer (score 0):

You give quite little information which is why I think it is hard to give you good help. However there are a couple of comments I would like to give:

- Perhaps the parser don't realize that the input is done and it hinges on either getting an EOL or getting another record. Hence it asks for a partial result. Try feeding it the equivalent of EOL in the hope it forces it.
- I can't remember the code, but using the Alternative instance might be detrimental to parsing performance. If that is the case, you may want to case on the comment and recordTypes.
- I use cereal for a lot of binary parsing and that is also extremely fast. attoparsec seems better as a text-parser though. You should definitely consider the option.
- Another option is to use iteratee-based IO in the longer run. John Lato did an excellent article on iteratees in the latest monad reader (issue #16 I believe). The end-of-line condition is the iteratees to signal. Beware though that the iteratee types are quite daunting and take some time getting used to.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I've tried reducing the parser to the minimal version that exhibits the problem, such as removing the alternatives and just having a sequence of comments.  In GHCi the comment function works as I expect, but the items function is problematic.  I was wondering if there was something fundamentally wrong with my approach.  I'm happy to share any extra information that might be useful.  I tried feeding it an extra EOL but it made no difference.  I saw iteratees mentioned in a few places but I've not encountered them before so I was trying to avoid them for the moment.