# understanding attoparsec

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

attoparsec was suggested to me for parsing a file, now I must to understand how to use it;
somebody gave me  this piece of code:

### #

```
type Environment = M.Map String String 
import Data.Attoparsec (maybeResult)
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
environment :: A.Parser Environment
environment = M.fromList <$> A.sepBy entry A.endOfLine
parseEnvironment = maybeResult .flip A.feed B.empty . A.parse environment
spaces = A.many $ A.char ' '
entry = (,) <$> upTo ':' <*> upTo ';'
upTo delimiter = B.unpack <$> A.takeWhile (A.notInClass $ delimiter : " ")
                      <* (spaces >> A.char delimiter >> spaces)
```

that works very well, but I do not know why:
what the reason of using flip, is it not easier to put the argument of A.feed in a different order? and why is there B.empty?
is there some tutorial about that I can study?
thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe the author used `pointfree`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an explanation of the need for `feed` in the answers to [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988988/problem-with-incomplete-input-when-using-attoparsec). As Bryan O'Sullivan (the creator of Attoparsec) says there:

> If you write an attoparsec parser that
>   consumes as much input as possible
>   before failing, you must tell the
>   partial result continuation when
>   you've reached the end of your input.

You can do this by feeding it an empty bytestring.

I'll admit that I wrote the code in question, and I actually didn't use `pointfree` in this case. Simple composition just makes sense to me here: you run the parser (`A.parse environment`), you tell it you're done (`flip A.feed B.empty`), and you convert to a `Maybe` as a kind of basic error handling (`maybeResult`). In my opinion this feels cleaner than the pointed version:

```
parseEnvironment b = maybeResult $ A.feed (A.parse environment b) B.empty
```

The rest is I think fairly idiomatic [applicative parsing](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/using-parsec.html#id652399), although I'm not sure why I would have used `>>` instead of `*>`.