# Haskell : how to stop Data.Attoparsec.Char8.sepBy when input String is empty?

Tags: parsing, haskell, attoparsec

i've wrote the following Haskell code

```
import Data.Attoparsec (Parser)
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B

someWithSep sep p = A.sepBy p sep
```

the code is suppose to work this way :

```
main*> A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89"
Done "" [123,45,67,89]
```

but since I've defined someWithSep like in the code written above, I always get the following behavior :

```
main*> A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89"
Partial _
```

unless I provide a corrupted entry :

```
main*> A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89f"
Done "f" [123,45,67,89]
```

How can I correct this ?

thanks to reply

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Partial` constructor doesn't indicate failure, merely that parsing could continue if you wanted it to.  You should take the Partial item and feed it the empty ByteString (as per the docs: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/attoparsec/0.8.1.0/doc/html/Data-Attoparsec-Char8.html#t:Result) to get the final result.

Just to show it works:

```
> let A.Partial f = A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89" in f B.empty
Done "" [123,45,67,89]
```

Of course, you probably want to have a case statement in the end to handle the other cases.

Comment: Addendum: The `feed` function in attoparsec can also be used to supply the empty string afterwards, so you could also use: `A.feed (A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89") B.empty`

Answer (score 2):

attoparsec accepts input in multiple pieces. One gives the first piece to **parse**, then gives the result from **parse** and the second piece to **feed**, then gives that result and the third piece to **feed** again, and so on.

You feed the parser an empty string to mark the end of input:

```
A.feed (A.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89") B.empty
Done "" [123,45,67,89]
```

Or use Data.Attoparsec.Lazy, where the lazy string handles the end of input for you:

```
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Lazy as L
import qualified Data.Attoparsec.Char8 as A
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as B
L.parse (someWithSep A.skipSpace A.decimal) $ B.pack "123 45  67 89"
Done "" [123,45,67,89]
```

(See also [this related Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988988/problem-with-incomplete-input-when-using-attoparsec))